# How can I get the numeric items of fetchAll?

Tags: php, pdo

Here is the result of my code:

```
$res = $stm->fetchAll();
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => apple
            [0] => apple
            [colour] => red
            [1] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => pear
            [0] => pear
            [colour] => green
            [1] => green
        )
)
```

And if I use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, the result will be:

```
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => apple
            [colour] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => pear
            [colour] => green
        )
)
```

---

Now I want to know, how can I get this ?

```
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => pear
            [1] => green
        )
)
```

Noted that `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` won't return the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**PDO::FETCH_NUM**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

try this

Comment: Don't mind the edit please. I was going to post that as an answer and saw yours so added the manual link there. +1

Comment: not a problem bro @HankyPanky i am always open to better suggestion, see i just started so dont have much idea, thanks for guiding me if i am wrong :) cheers bro

Comment: It should also be noted that you can always access array elements by their numeric index even if you `FETCH_ASSOC`